# ASM , calling functions with asm

Tags: function, assembly

I want to call a function which is in address 774a7fdch(kernel32.dll function) with ASM inside a C++ Program

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 .

how can I do it?

```
call 774a7fdch
```

doesn't work, how can I pass call the function address?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem in VS2010 before.
try call [0x774a7fdc]

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with the CALL instruction, it's position dependent. It's encoded as:

```
E8 XX XX XX XX
```

Where the X's are the *distance* from the memory address of the next instruction to the address of the function you're calling. This distance is also known as *delta offset*.

If you can't know where your code will be in memory in order to do the calculation, you could try loading the address in a register instead:

```
mov eax, 774a7fdch
call eax
```

That would be 7 bytes instead of 5, though.

Also, as another user pointed out, hardcoding the addresses of functions is probably a bad idea since they can move around.

I don't know if this solves your problem or not, because I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

Should work with

```
call dword ptr 0x774a7fdc
```

Comment: It says "Improper operand type"... :S